# No delegate when remote notification received

Tags: objective-c, delegates, icarousel, remote-notifications

I have a `MainViewController` which has `delegate` and `datasource` for an iCarousel item. Everything works fine while working within the app.

Inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method I coded below line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fetchAndLoad" object:nil];
```

This calls a `MainViewController` function which in turn calls the `reloadData` function for iCarousel. I'm sure that    fetchAndLoad is being called, but the   `reloadData` is not. The reloadData is being called only when the app enters foreground again.

Does this problem have something to do with the `MainViewController` delegate and how can I solve this?

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification was deprecated

Comment: excuse me, i meant   " -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler"

Comment: To clarify: MainViewController has some delegate methods, the reloadData function is an iCarousel function. Any suggestions?